# What kind of vegetable has pink and white concentric rings?

Tags: vegetables, food-identification

What kind of vegetable is pictured here with the pink and white concentric rings? They look like they might be some kind of beet or radish.

[image: Eel and Bone Marrow, Eggplant, and Pickled Vegetables by Chef Dan Hunter]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

That is a chioggia beet, I believe, but watermelon radish is also colored similarly.

Comment: The yellow and dark red slices are also different kinds of beets. Seems like a beet mix to me. :P

Comment: Those are some phat beets!

Comment: Also known as candy cane beets (because of appearance- does not taste like a peppermint stick!)

Comment: @Gretel_f - if you wouldn't mind, what are those beets?

Comment: @Alex Reinking - difficult to say, there are multiple yellow and red varieties. Check the Wikipedia article on beetroots for a rough list. The dark red one is the most common, though. Also i believe there are white ones, so the larger white slices could those. Side note: It's a bit sad to say, but those lovely rings will mostly disappear when cooking them. :( The dark red color is preserved, though.

Comment: And as a tip: when handling raw beets, especially the red ones, always wear gloves. That colorant is persistent as hell. ;) It's called betanin and is used as a natural red food colorant for example in tomato sauce or fruit juices and stuff. Consumed in large quantities it can color your urine as well. It's not toxic, though. :P just a bit shocking the first time you see it.

Comment: @Gretel_f - thanks! Maybe you could get away with pickling them without getting rid of the color?

Comment: @AlexReinking - I guess that could work. I haven't done it, though. Maybe you could ask a separate question about that. :)